# How can I set items(textbox, img...) on the second (window2) window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a mainwindow, and when it starts, i want to open another one, and put something on it. how it is possible if i declare the second window  like that:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    Window Window2 = new Window();
    Window2.Show();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Comment: Create a new window in your Visual Studio project, e.g. context menu -> Add -> Window... Then create a new instance of that window class and show it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `Content` property of the new window to anything you want, for example a `UserControl` that you have created using the Project->Add menu in Visual Studio:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Window win = new Window() { Width = 100, Height = 100 };
    win.Content = new UserControl1();
    win.Show();
}
```